# I need to use WebDriverWait in appium-Python and I need to pass "ios_predicate" as a Locator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriverwait, python-appium

Working in iOS mobile automation using selenium and appium, I need to use explicitwait for Predicate or class_chain, since ExpectedConditions will accept only locators, how can I pass my Predicate or class_chain which is saved as a string in my EC condition

I need to pass a string as a locator since I tried but it is not accepting.

I have tried:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expectedconditions as EC

string_predicate = "type == 'XCUIElementTypeStaticText' AND value BEGINSWITH[c] 'Hi'"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

waiting_for = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_ios_predicate(string_predicate)))
```

I know that `EC.visibility_of_element_located()` should accept only default locators like ID,XPATH etc.. But I need to pass a string which is saved as Predicate or class_chain. This is blocking my work completely.

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

string_predicate = (MobileBy.IOS_PREDICATE, "type == 'XCUIElementTypeStaticText' AND value BEGINSWITH[c] 'Hi'")
string_id = (MobileBy.ID, "Hi")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(string_predicate))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(string_id))
```